# Wordpress - Not able to update stylesheets for ie7 and 8

Tags: css

I am here to find out why the stylesheets for ie7 and 8 are not updating anymore after a while. I thought that I might type something by accident but I triple checked and there are no additional typo.

The original stylesheet is updating to all firefox and IE but conditional for ie7 and 8 seem not to be working anymore

I have been struggling to make ie7 and ie8 stylesheet updated.

Insight or help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a cache issue.

An easy override that might help is to put a question mark and the revision number after the filename in the CSS tag: style.css?12

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?12">
```

If you update the string after the ? it will refresh the stylesheet from the cache.

Hope this helps

Comment: some replenishing: you can disable IE8's cache in the developer tool.